# Generate multiple R-files in different namespaces (Android in Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using a library which expects a couple of id's and values in R. The problem is that it is hard coded into the library in what namespace the R is in.

I can solve the problem by copying the R class into the other namespace, but it would be easier to autogenerate two R-files.

Another solution could be some sort of wrapper-class, the problem here is that the values must be constants.

Maybe run some sort of script every time the R is generated? How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANT script for this.

But what are your intends for using 2 different R files? 
If you are creating 2 versions of you app you could make the ANT script make separate projects  on building/releasing and then you could continue developing in your current project.

Comment: I use a third party library that expects a couple of values from the Resource file. The problem is that he has used imports against his namespace (don't ask me why). I'm new at android development, could you point me in the right direction on how to do this with ANT?

Comment: Are you using eclipse for developing?

you can try to clean the project files in eclipse:

Project => "Clean..." (This will rebuild your project from scratch and therefore regenerate your R.java)

if that doesn't work:
Manually delete all R.java and save (located in /gen/)
Delete your external library project and readd it.

Comment: I would like get two different R.java inside two different namespaces (the defeault namespace and one that i decide the namespace for).

Comment: If I am correct eclipse is already generating multiple R files when you have third party lib, you can check that in the gen folder. If it does exists then you need to import the 2nd R file to you source code

Comment: I guess you are right. It does work, but I can't see the R.java for my third party lib. Thanks.